# What does m% stand for?

Tags: analog, datasheet, gain, instrumentation-amplifier, error

What does m% mean?

Like in this datasheet from TI at the gain error graphs: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina149-ep.pdf?&ts=1589388038122

Is it supposed to mean per-cent-mille (10^-5) or per-mille (10^-3) or ppm (10^-6)?

Update:
Here is an other datasheet with the same unit: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina226.pdf?&ts=1589357516155

Here the gain error is given without a unit in the table section (unlike in the first one where it is %FSR), but the values still don't match up with the graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about figure 33, looks like they're plotting 1000x the error in %. So milli-percent.

Maximum gain error is 0.047% so that would be 47, which fits with the graph.

[image]

Comment: 27, 29, 33, and 34. Does 0.047% fit the graphs though? Because that is where I got really uncertain. The maximum in the graph is just 20. That is significantly less than the maximum 47 and a lot more than the typical 5 they specify in the table section (on page 4). Plus the 0.047 is given in %FSR, is the graph in FSR as well or it is showing the real gain error? I honestly am so confused...

Comment: One is typical and the other is guaranteed maximum. Typical is stated as +/-5 which matches Figure 27. It does not match Fig 33, which makes me think that +/-5 is only at 25°C, despite what the datasheet says. Typical numbers are not guaranteed, of course. An almost 10:1 difference between typical and maximum is a bit much in this case. It's not unusual for there to be a large difference between typical and maximum. 2:1 or 3:1 is common. Sometimes, for relatively unimportant things like leakage on digital inputs that are hard to test quickly, the difference might be many orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 6):

It must be a [per cent mille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_cent_mille) (milli per cent) or 10⁻⁵. I have no idea why TI decided to use such an obscure unit in a data sheet. It is occasionally used in other fields of engineering, but I have never seen it used in electronics.

Comment: National always had better datasheets - I don't know why TI was unable to utilize these skills when they purchased National Semi

Comment: Isn't it obvious? They reassigned all the NatSemi technical writers to menial duties or let them go, it's a natural part of the acquisitions process!